# Selenium, How can I block location "alert" from chrome?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I'm using Selenium and can't block chrome location "alert"...

[image: location_alert]

I tried two options without success...

**First option without success:**

```
ChromeOptions chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();
chromeProfile.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
driver = new ChromeDriver(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["driverChrome"], chromeProfile);
```

**Second option without success:**
I used `ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent();`, but it seems that chrome doesn't detect it as an `alert`.

```
        public bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            bool presenceOfAlert = false;
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) /*timeout in seconds*/);
            try
            {
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
                presenceOfAlert = true;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                presenceOfAlert = false;
            }
            return presenceOfAlert;
        }

        private void RemoveLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsAlertPresent())
                {
                    var location = driver.LocationContext;
                    IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                //treure modal geolocation
                WaitForElementToDisplay(By.CssSelector("#application > div > div.overview-body > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.otui-modal-container > div.otui-modal > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.modal-footer > button"), driver);
                var geolocationDialog = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#application > div > div.overview-body > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.otui-modal-container > div.otui-modal > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.modal-footer > button");
                geolocationDialog.Click();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                logger.Error("RemoveLocation: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

I followed the [documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/handle-permission-pop-ups#c_sharp) but not working...

```
                Dictionary<string, object> locationOption = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                // 0 - Default, 1 - Allow, 2 - Block
                locationOption.Add("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2);
                // INIT CHROME OPTIONS
                Dictionary<string, object> chromeOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                // SET CHROME OPTIONS
                chromeOptions.Add("prefs", locationOption);
                chromeProfile.AddAdditionalCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions, true);
                //chromeProfile.AddArgument("--headless");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["driverChrome"], chromeProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `--disable-notifications` chrome flag